# WooCommerce Product Search plugin

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I have installed the WooCommerce Product Search in my site and all works fine, but there is a small issue with the result page shown.

The result page used is the same than the one used as the main shop page, so the issue is that one slider and info should not be shown in the result page. This content has been put into the description textarea within the Edit Page using short codes.

I have the archive-product.php file open and do not know to avoid this.

I think I should use the is_search() function to check if page should renders on one way or another, but do not know what part of the code treat the info from the page description.

Comment: The plugin may allow for it own template.  Check it's documentation

Comment: it does not permit it.

Comment: does your theme contain search.php in the root?

Comment: I've check it out now and it does not have such file. I have included a search.php in the root of the theme and no effect.

Comment: What did you put inside search.php?

Comment: possible duplicate of [woo commerce search result template](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23490317/woo-commerce-search-result-template)