# Targeting the shop page only

Tags: css, wordpress, woocommerce

**This is what I need to do:**

- To target **only** the main shop page with CSS (a specific custom class I created as mentioned below).

**This is what I've done and tried so far:**

- I have an override template of `archive-product.php` in my child theme.
- In this override template I've added a div with a custom class `custom-shop-class` just before the product loop start, because I want to target the looped products specifically.
- I tried targeting with class `page-id-4` because if I hover over the "shop" page in wp-admin, it gave me `http://.../post.php?post=4&action=edit`

**The problem I'm having is as follows:**

- From what I've discovered is that the same `archive-product.php` template is being used in the other various shop pages and not only in the main "shop" page (correct me if I'm wrong), so when I target my `custom-shop-class` with CSS, it affects all the other shop pages using the same template file, and it must not.
- There is no unique identifier or class specifically for the shop page, something like the `page-id-??` class in the body tag (as in the usual WP pages).

Any suggestions on the best method/solution?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Set a conditional statement to check for the primary shop page, then echo the div in question if that statement evaluates to true.

**WooCommerce Conditional Tag for main shop page:**

```
is_shop()
```

**Example**

```
if (is_shop()) {
echo "<div class='custom-shop-class'></div>";
} else {
echo "<div class='custom-product-category-class'></div>";
}
```

**Alternatively:**

```
<?php if (is_shop()):?>
<div class="custom-shop-class"></div>
<?php else: ?>
<div class="custom-product-category-class"></div>
<?php endif;?>
```

[Conditional Tags | WooThemes Documentation](https://docs.woothemes.com/document/conditional-tags/)

Comment: Beautiful! A great (simple) solution and makes logical sense! Just a quick question, what is "is_shop"? Is it a variable or a function and where do I find it in the WC scheme of things?

Comment: Fantastic! Glad you came right. WooCommerce make it easy in this way to hook in custom actions and filters.
If you feel this answer gave you the solution you were looking for, please feel free to mark it as the correct answer.

Comment: Nevermind my question. I only now saw the link you attached about "conditional tags". Brilliant, thank you!

Comment: To answer your question, is_shop() is just a conditional query tag that have a close working relationship with the Wordpress template hierarchy. for more information, check out: https://codex.wordpress.org/Conditional_Tags

Comment: Thank you very much for replying. I have some reading to do, much appreciated.

Comment: Forgot to mention and to avoid confusion if others are following.. I did not use the div you mentioned after the ELSE. I placed again the usual loop that was there originally (all the code from `<?php woocommerce_product_loop_start(); ?>` to `<?php woocommerce_product_loop_end(); ?>` )

Comment: I picked up a minor issue today, with the "woocommerce product search" plugin I installed previously, which seems to use the same template and also tagged as `is_shop`. So this page gets affected by the above code https://docs.woothemes.com/document/woocommerce-product-search/api/. I tried something like `<?php if ( is_shop() && !woocommerce_product_search() ):?>` but this didn't work. Any idea there? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try using the `is_search()` conditional query tag instead.
For more information: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23490317/woo-commerce-search-result-template

Comment: That worked! Buddy, if you were here, I'd buy you a beer right now. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Using the filter `body_class` with the `is_shop` conditional you can target the main WooCommerce shop page.

```
add_filter( 'body_class', 'woo_shop_class' );
// Add WooCommerce Shop Page CSS Class
function woo_shop_class( $classes ) {
  if ( is_shop() )  // Set conditional
    $classes[] = 'woo-shop'; // Add Class
return $classes;
}
```

The code goes in your themes `functions.php` file.

Comment: Very handy. This way same end result is achieved without use of a template file. Can implement this via functions.php, which is exactly what I needed. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

To build on the answer provided here, how might I go further and add a unique identifier to the shop page based on the active WPML language? (I'm basically trying to reduce a font size on the German version of the shop page only - it's proving surprisingly difficult to do)