# How to modify WooCommerce search results?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I reckon the WooCommerce search is using a URL like http://localhost/myshoesssite/?s=noheelshoes&post_type=product

Thus, I need to edit the search result so that I could add a URL parameter at the end of each product URL, like http://localhost/myshoesssite/product/no-heel-shoes?get=specs where get=specs is the parameter. I only wish to add this parameter in my search results, NOT in my typical product URL.

I tried using search.php in my theme but seems like when I edit the file, the search results don't change. Below is my search.php

```
<?php
/**
 * The template for displaying search results pages.
 *
 * @link https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/template-hierarchy/#search-result
 *
 * 
 */

get_header(); ?>

<div id="primary" class="site-content content-wrapper topofset">
    <div id="main" class="container" >
        <div class="content content_search" >
            <?php
            if ( have_posts() ) : ?>

                <header class="page-header">
                    <h1 class="page-title text-light"><?php printf( esc_html__( 'Search Results for: %s', 'myticket' ), '<span>' . get_search_query() . '</span>' ); ?></h1>
                </header><!-- .page-header -->

                <?php
                /* Start the Loop */
                while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>

                     <span class="search-post-title">Testing<?php the_title(); ?></span>
            <span class="search-post-excerpt"><?php the_excerpt(); ?></span>
            <span class="search-post-link"><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_permalink(); ?></a></span>


                    <?php
                    /**
                     * Run the loop for the search to output the results.
                     * If you want to overload this in a child theme then include a file
                     * called content-search.php and that will be used instead.
                     */
                    //get_template_part( 'template-parts/content', 'search' );

                endwhile;

            else :

                get_template_part( 'template-parts/content', 'none' );

            endif; ?>
        </div>
    </div><!-- #main -->
</div><!-- #primary -->

<?php
get_footer();
```

How do I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly,  make sure you have a copy of archive-product.php under wp-content/themes/yourtheme/woocommerce folder. You can copy that file from wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/templates

Inside archive-product.php, you got to differentiate your search results between those appearing from the search and those appearing in the shop page because both are sharing the same template. Use something like below..taken from [WooCommerce search result template](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23490317/woocommerce-search-result-template)

```
if ( is_search() ) {
    //put your search results markup here (you can copy some code from archive-product.php file and also from content-product.php to create a standard markup
} else {
    // here goes the content that is already in that file (archive-product.php) 
}
```

It is within the is_search() if statement that you edit the search results as you wish. You could create another copy of content-product.php (again, copying from woocommerce template to your theme's folder) and inside that is where you get to customize your search results. You could override the hooks such as "woocommerce_before_shop_loop_item" by placing your new functions in functions.php under your theme folder.

Answer (score 1):

It's easy, add this code to functions.php file:

```
function after_setup_theme_7cloner_com() {
    add_theme_support(
        'html5',
        array(
            'comment-form',
            'comment-list',
            'gallery',
            'caption',
            'style',
            'script',
            'navigation-widgets',
        )
    );

    add_theme_support( 'woocommerce' );
}
add_action( 'after_setup_theme', 'after_setup_theme_7cloner_com' );
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! While this code may solve the question, including an explanation of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.